# Trying to use single Angular component as template for multiple HTML content

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm an Angular rookie trying to use the single component @comic-story as a template multiple comics, ultimately to make individual comic URLs (local for dev):

- http://localhost:4200/bottle-of-red
- http://localhost:4200/franks-next-mission
- http://localhost:4200/i-did-nothing

Each comic is a single page with a carousel with elaborate HTML:

```html
<main>
 <section class="comic-book-story">
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Bottle of Red</h1>
   <p>...</p>
   <div id="" class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
      <p class="page-label">Bottle of Red: Page 1 of 7</p>
      <img>
      <div class="button-row">
       <a href="#">Previous</a>
       <a href="#">Next</a>
      </div>
      <div class="author-notes">
       <h2>About This Page</h2>
       <p>...</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      ...
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      ...
     </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-prev"></a>
    <a class="carousel-next"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section class="comic-book-info text-page">
  <div class="container">
   <h2>Story Notes</h2>
   <p>...</p>
  </div>
 </div>    
</main>
```

My current directory tree from app:

comic-story/
|- comic-story.component.html
|- comic-story.component.scss
|- comic-story.component.spec.ts
|- comic-story.component.ts

|- comics/
|- |- bottle-of-red.component.html
|- |- bottle-of-red.component.scss
|- |- bottle-of-red.component.spec.ts
|- |- bottle-of-red.component.ts
|- |- franks-next-mission.component.html
|- |- franks-next-mission.component.scss
|- |- franks-next-mission.component.spec.ts
|- |- franks-next-mission.component.ts
|- |- i-did-nothing.component.html
|- |- i-did-nothing.component.scss
|- |- i-did-nothing.component.spec.ts
|- |- i-did-nothing.component.ts

[my directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10PBc.png)

What's the best way of hooking this up?

Comment: I would suggest creating a component and filling the content dynamically. Since, the styling for the comics is the same and only the content different. That way, it will be less work for you. Rather than creating pages for each comics.

Comment: I agree with @SunilLama, and also you should use Angular Router

Comment: Sounds brilliant. I'm a rookie: how do I dynamically fill in the content?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stackblitz link showing how I do it using Angular Router,
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8ba2n)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for this. Much to study. I don't have a database. Do I need to learn how to build one, or is there a more static solution?

Comment: if you don't want to use a database you can store data as a json file or an array in your component

Comment: @DavidMarshall I updated the code so you won't need a Database

Comment: This is fantastic! My only question: since the per-comic markup is so elaborate, can the array point to html assets instead of ID, name, and description fields?

Comment: @DavidMarshall you don't need to have many HTML file , you just need to create one template file, where you use the ID to display data related to that ID, with that you won't have to worry about how many HTML pages you must have, SO I DON"T RECOMMEND THAT. but if you want to point to another page you just have to create all those pages , add then to router.module and navigate to them.

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought of using an HTML file for each comic/carousel page because I already have them from an older version of the site. This template idea is intriguing. Is there a Stackblitz with an example I can study from?

Comment: @DavidMarshall the stackblitz link above has the example you require, you just need to understand how the Angular Router works and also Angular Modules. understand both Angular Modules and Angular Router will make it easy to structure your app the way you want. here is a youtube channel explaining router https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np3ULAMqwNo

Comment: Thanks for this. My time is a little split, hence the slow response time. Hope to re-engage later tonight.

Comment: Quick note to thank @Sivuyile again. Other tasks are still blocking me, but this is gold.